# Syntax error near unexpected token 'elif' - cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I'm new to shell scripting, the following is the script that I have currently.

```
os=$(uname -a)
if [[ $os == *"Linux"* ]];
then
    val=$(~/local/bin/python2.7 Main.py)
elif [[ $os = *"CYGWIN_NT"* ]]
then
    val=$(python Main.py)
fi
```

I get an error

```
-bash: ./run.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'bash: ./run.sh: line 8: `elif [[ $os = *"CYGWIN_NT"* ]]
```

Trying to run it from Cygwin bash shell.

Comment: Try checking your script using [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net/)

Comment: `dos2unix run-nw` this one worked.